# Create a variable dataset out of proc contents

Tags: sas

How to use ODS TRACE to identify name of the PROC CONTENTS results output object that contains the variable name, type, length, format and informat, and save these results as new SAS datasets.

my code:

```
ods select Variables;
proc contents data=mylib.hotel1 out=work.h1;
run;
ods select default;
```

but output dataset is different from result.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to select the ODS table since `out=` already contains this information. If you really do want to use ODS, you can identify the table in the log with `ods trace`.

```
ods trace on;

proc contents data=sashelp.cars;
run;

ods trace off;
```

Check the log and you will see the dataset containing all variables:

```
Output Added:
-------------
Name:       Variables
Label:      Variables
Template:   Base.Contents.Variables
Path:       Contents.DataSet.Variables
-------------
```

You can save this with the `ods output` statement in `proc contents`.

```
proc contents data=sashelp.cars;
    ods output variables=variables;
run;
```

You will receive an output dataset called `variables`.

[image]